# Regarding extensions of finite groups by Tori

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, group-cohomology

I know how to prove the following result. However, my proof is a little bit long and complicated and only uses fairly low tech results in group cohomology. It would be nice if I could find a citation in the literature that directly implies this claim but I am not experienced in group theory or homological algebra and to be honest I'm not sure where to start looking for such a result.

> **Lemma**: Suppose $\mathbb{T}^n = \mathbb{R}^n/ \mathbb{Z}^n $ is the standard $n$-dimensional torus and $\Gamma$ is a finite group of order $k$. Consider a short exact sequence:
> $$ 0 \to \mathbb{T}^n \to E \to \Gamma \to 1. $$
> Suppose $ R := \{ t \in \mathbb{T}^n \mathrel| kt = 0  \} $. Then the following short exact sequence splits:
> $$ 0 \to \mathbb{T}^n/R \to E/R \to \Gamma \to 1. $$

The proof basically boils down to the fact that $ H^2( \Gamma, \mathbb{T}^n) $ is annihilated by $k$ and using that to show that the induced map $ H^2(\Gamma, \mathbb{T}^n) \to H^2(\Gamma, \mathbb{T}^n/R) $ is the zero map and therefore the curvature class of the top short exact sequence projects to zero.

I guess the things I would like to know are:

- Is this 'obvious' to those experienced with finite group extensions or Lie theory?
- Is there a textbook/paper where I can find a result or exercise that directly implies this lemma?

Comment: Using `\text` inside math mode for formatting results in funny-looking text.  Use **stars** **stars**` rather than $\textbf{textbf}$ `$\textbf{textbf}$`.  I have edited accordingly.  (Also, I think that this is an interesting question!)

Comment: Yes, it is almost  obvious.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, as a sorta-Lie theorist for whom it is not obvious, would you be willing to explain why it should be obvious?

Comment: It is *almost* obvious, see my one-page answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I write an answer rather than a comment in order to accommodate exact sequences.)

Let
$$0\to T\to E\to\Gamma\to 1\tag{$E_1$}$$
be your first  group extension, where $T$ is the torus ${\Bbb R}^n/{\Bbb Z}^n$.
Write $R_k\subset T$ for the kernel of multiplication by $k$ in $T$
and consider your second exact sequence
$$0\to T/R_k\to E/R_k\to\Gamma\to 1.\tag{$E_2$}$$
To the  extension $(E_1)$ we associate its cohomology class $\eta_1\in H^2(\Gamma,T)$, and to extension $(E_2)$ we associate its class $\eta_2\in H^2(\Gamma,T/R_k)$.
Then it follows from the constructions of $\eta_1$ and $\eta_2$ that $\eta_2$ is the image of $\eta_1$ under the homomorphism
$$\phi_*\colon H^2(\Gamma,T) \to H^2(\Gamma,T/R_k)$$
induced by the canonical homomorphism
$$\phi\colon T\to T/R_k.$$
We have not yet used the assumption that $T$ is a torus and that $\#\Gamma=k$.

Now consider the *surjective* homomorphism
$$\alpha\colon  T\to T,\quad x\mapsto kx.$$
Its kernel is $R_k$, and so it induces an isomorphism
$$\alpha_*\colon T/R_k\to T.$$
Identifying $T/R_k$ with $T$ using $\alpha_*$, we obtain that our
$$\phi\colon T\to T$$
is multiplication by $k$.
It follows that
$$\phi_*\colon H^2(\Gamma,T) \to H^2(\Gamma,T)$$
is multiplication by $k$ as well.
Since $\Gamma$ is a group of order $k$, multiplication by $k$ annihilates $H^2(\Gamma,T)$.
See Corollary 1 of Proposition 8 in Section 6, page 105, of:
Atiyah and Wall, Cohomology of groups, in: Cassels and Fröhlich (eds.), Algebraic Number Theory, Acad. Press 1967, pp. 94-115. It follows that $\eta_2=0$ and the sequence $(E_2)$ splits.

Comment: Without details from @JoelVillatoro it's hard to know for sure, but this seems similar to the proof that they very briefly sketched in the post.

Comment: The argument uses only the following property of $T$: the map $$T\to T, \quad x\mapsto kx$$ is surjective.

Comment: @LSpice: OP complained that his proof is low tech. Mine is not.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, thank you very much for your reply. Your proof here is certainly much better than the one I wrote originally. Certainly more efficient.